# Howto use Git behind MFA (Azure Application Proxy)?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket

I have a test-setup with Bitbucket Server running on intranet and published over Azure Application Proxy to allow internet access while using MFA.

This works nicely for the web interface and I have been able to confirm git functionality by copying a fresh cookie from a web session to *http.cookiefile*.

However, I was hoping to be able to enable the use of Microsoft's *git-credential-manager* to take care of the MFA step, but so far without luck. If I understand correctly, the credentials manager never kicks in since I never get an rejection due to lack of credentials. Instead my git client bails out on a redirect towards login.microsoftonline.com.

```
○ git clone https://git.foo.bar/scm/foo/example.git
Cloning into 'example'...
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://git.foo.bar/scm/foo/example.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
   redirect: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-some-guid-xxxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=....
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working?

**References:**

- https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/wiki/How-the-Git-Credential-Managers-works
- https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux
- http://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Comment: Even the Git credential manager depends on the creation of a Personal Access Token in AzureDevOps (it creates one upin succesful authorization and that's what Git uses under the hood. The Git commandline doesn't support true interactive authentication prompts.